# multiple "pages" in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, routes, html

I am using node.js, and my server only has one port open for me to use node.js on. And no, I cannot open more ports. Because I am using this same server for testing and production and it seems like it would be more convenient, I want to be able to have node.js "pages", like in php. Basically, if the url is something, I want the code in one node.js file to be executed. If the url is something else, I want a different node.js script to be run. I want it so that if one page crashes, the rest of the website stays up. I think there might be a way to do this with express, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: For anybody that's interested, I ended up making a simple package to do this. I know I could've used a proxy, but I liked my way better: https://www.npmjs.com/package/projectile it's not very complete or documented yet, but the examples directory is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with express.  You want to use routes within express.  Check out:http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB

Also check out:  http://elegantcode.com/2012/01/20/taking-toddler-steps-with-node-js-express-routing/

Comment: First off, all the code still has to be in the same file. Second, the server will still crash if code for any page causes an error

Comment: No, I said I want the code to be in different files. How would I do that?

Comment: Check out the links I sent- I think you'll find express does meet your requirements.

Comment: Note that within each app. call you can then call out to functions in another node.js file.  If you really need a whole different nodejs server for each route you'll need something external to do the routing.  But in the case described node.js/express handles that routing- which has a good chance of working better for you.